# Make AutomateWoo checkbox required on WooCommerce registration

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, registration

The AutomateWoo plugin adds a checkbox field on the registration section *(located on My Account page when user is not logged in)* and I am trying here to make it required.

I don't want people to be able to register without ticking this box.

The box is an optin and displays as follows:

```
<p class="automatewoo-optin form-row">
    <label class="woocommerce-form__label woocommerce-form__label-for-checkbox checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" class="woocommerce-form__input woocommerce-form__input-checkbox input-checkbox" name="automatewoo_optin" id="automatewoo_optin">
        <span class="automatewoo-optin__checkbox-text">I want to receive updates about products and promotions.</span>
    </label>
</p>
```

Here is my code attempt to make this checkbox "required":

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_register_form_start', 'bd_require_automatewoo_optin');
function bd_require_automatewoo_optin( $fields ) {
$fields['automatewoo_optin']['required'] = true;
return $fields;
}
```

I have also tried using `woocommerce_register_form` and `woocommerce_forms_field` hooks.

Image preview of the "Register" form, checkbox is located at the bottom.

[image: Checkbox added to the bottom of the register form, must be made required.]

How can I make Make AutomateWoo checkbox required on WooCommerce registration section?

---

#### Edit:

In some cases, you may need to replace the second 'required' with 'true'…

```html
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
   $('input[name="automatewoo_optin"]').prop('required', 'required');
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

To make your checkbox field located on WooCommerce registration form required, use the following:

```php
// Validate WooCommerce registration form custom fields.
add_action( 'woocommerce_register_post', 'wc_validate_automatewoo_optin_fields', 10, 3 );
function wc_validate_automatewoo_optin_fields( $username, $email, $validation_errors ) {
    if ( ! isset($_POST['automatewoo_optin']) || empty($_POST['automatewoo_optin']) ) {
        $validation_errors->add('optin_error', __('The Checkbox is a required field', 'woocommerce') );
    }
        
    return $validation_errors;
}
```

Then *optionally* use also the following to make your checkbox field visually required:

```php
// Mark the checkbox field as required
add_filter( 'woocommerce_register_form_end', 'add_automatewoo_optin_jquery');
function add_automatewoo_optin_jquery() {
    ?>
    <script>
    (function($){
       $('p.automatewoo-optin').addClass('validate-required');
       $('p.automatewoo-optin > label > span').append('<abbr class="required" title="required">*</abbr>');
    })(jQuery);
    </script>
    <?php
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: +1 Thanks Loic this answer works much better, after some testing using Howard's jQuery method I found an issue on the checkout page where the field was being ignored and registration was possible without ticking it.

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery.  Either add to your theme scripts, or you can add to `wp_footer` and wrap in `<script> </script>`

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
   $('input[name="automatewoo_optin"]').prop('checked', true);
});
```

Comment: Ahh I did not think of this. This jQuery automatically ticks the checkbox. How can we make it so the field is NOT selected but the user must tick it before submitting the form ?